# How can we find Google Analytics tracking tags of completed campaigns?

Tags: google-analytics, mailchimp

We've connected our MailChimp account to Google Analytics, and are setting GA tracking tags for all new emails to allow us to monitor performance.

While we're trying to follow a naming convention for tracking tags, sometimes it would be helpful to go back to a completed campaign and check what the tracking tag was.

I would have thought it'd be possible to do this, but I've not been able to find the GA tracking tag anywhere in the details of completed campaigns on the MailChimp site, or in completed campaign reports.

Is it somewhere that I've not found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got in touch with MailChimp support to ask whether this is possible. Their answer as follows:

> You would not be able to find it in MailChimp without replicating the
>   campaign you want to check the GA Tracking tag on. When replicating a
>   campaign it will leave settings the same as you had it before you sent
>   the campaign. I will leave feedback for our developers since I can see
>   the importance of being able to see the GA Tracking code in the report
>   section of MailChimp.
>
> In order to replicate the campaign you want to check the GA tracking
>   code on you have to go to the Campaigns page >> Right click the
>   drop-down arrow by edit >> Click on Replicate. Once replicated it will
>   show the settings that were used when the campaign was sent.
>
> For more information on replicating a campaign check out this article
>   Replicate a Campaign: http://eepurl.com/de9s2v